# conditional statements and ie blank page?

Tags: css, html, conditional-statements, google-font-api

Thought these were working fine, but upon just checking I get a blank page in ie9.  If I use developer tools to switch to ie 8 or 7 the same result.  Maybe I am just too tired to right now, but I'm not seeing anything wrong with the below to cause a problem.

The top adds a class to html ie 8 or lower so I can remove any use of the google fonts in my css.  then the bottom loads the google fonts for anything not IE OR IE 9 or higher.

What is wrong with this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lte IE 8 ]> <html class="ie8" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
<meta name="description" content="test">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kite+One|Open+Sans:400italic,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kite+One|Open+Sans:400italic,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: There is no reason to use javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about these lines:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kite+One|Open+Sans:400italic,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Shouldn't they be:

```
<!--[if !IE]> <html lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kite+One|Open+Sans:400italic,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <![endif]-->
```

?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your last conditional statement is messed up.

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
```

remove the extra

```
<!-->
```

and where it closes

```
<!--<![endif]-->
```

change it to

```
<![endif]-->
```